# how to allow assignment from float to int by using template class

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have a template class, given below :

```
class Item
{
    T Data;
public:
    Item(): 
        Data()
    {}

    void SetData(T nValue)
    {
        Data = nValue;
    }

    T GetData() const
    {
        return Data;
    }

    void PrintData()
    {
        cout << Data;
    }
};
```

It is possible to do the following :

```
Item<int> item1;
Item<int> item2;
item1 = item2;
```

But when I do the follwing, I get compile time error:

```
Item<int> item1;
Item<float> item2;
item1 = item2;
```

Clearly, compiler does not allow to it because `item1` is of **int type** but item2 is of **float type**.

How can I achieve the second part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you need a templated assignment operator, like this:

```
template <typename T>
class Item {
/* more */
public:
    template <typename U>
    Item &operator=(const Item<U> &ref)
    {
        Data = ref.Data;
        return *this;
    };
/* more */
};
```

In addition to that, you might need or want a templated copy constructor:

```
template <typename U>
Item(const Item<U> &ref):
    Data(ref.Data)
{

};
```

This allows for:

```
Item<int> foo;
Item<float> bar(foo);
```

Comment: how to define Item &operator=(const Item<U> &ref) outside item class?

Comment: Thats not possible. The assignment operators, [among others](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators#Overloaded_operators), cannot be non-member functions.

Comment: what i meant is how can i provide definition of "operator ="class outside class. i.e inside class item just have declaration Item &operator=(const Item<U> &ref); but defination is provided outside class ,how can i achieve this ?

Comment: In this case, you cannot really do that, because the operator is a template. You could write ``template<typename U> Item &operator=...`` inside the class and have *in the header file* a definition like ``template<typename U> Item &Item::operator=...``, but I don’t think this improves readability. You cannot have the definition in a non-header file, because it is a template.